# Login fails when checking params in before_action method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

```
Rails 5.1
devise 4.3.0
```

In config/routes.rb, I have:

```
devise_for :users, controllers: {
    sessions: 'users/sessions',
    confirmations: 'users/confirmations',
    passwords: 'users/passwords',
    registrations: 'users/registrations',
    unlocks: 'users/unlocks',
    invitations: 'users/invitations'
}
```

In app/controllers/users/sessions_controller.rb, I have:

```
class Users::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  before_action :configure_sign_in_params, only: [:create]

  def new
    super
  end

  def create
    super
  end

  def destroy
    super
  end

  protected

  def configure_sign_in_params
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_in, keys: [:attribute])
  end
end
```

When I try to login, I get the following error:

```
NoMethodError in Users::SessionsController#create
undefined method `concat' for #<Proc:0x00007f634da41ea8>
```

and it points to this line in app/controllers/users/sessions_controller.rb, as the source of the error.

```
devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_in, keys: [:attribute])
```

The request parameters are:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
  "authenticity_token"=>"..........",
  "user"=>{"email"=>"myemail@myemail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "remember_me"=>"0"},
  "commit"=>"Log In",
  "format"=>"user"}
```

If I comment out the before_action line in the controller, I get the following error:

```
ActionController::UnknownFormat in Users::SessionsController#create
ActionController::UnknownFormat
Extracted source (around line #11):

def create
 super (this would be line 11)
```

end

If, instead, I click on Change Password, I am emailed a link, and when I click on it, it allows me to change the password, and I'm logged in fine.

Here's the controllers/users/passwordds_controller.rb:

```
class Users::PasswordsController < Devise::PasswordsController
  def new
    super
  end

  def create
    super
  end

  def edit
    super
  end

  def update
    super
  end

  protected

  def after_resetting_password_path_for(resource)
    super(resource)
  end

  def after_sending_reset_password_instructions_path_for(resource_name)
    super(resource_name)
  end
end
```

Any ideas why it's failing when checking the params in the configure_sign_in_params method?

Comment: Think this: `devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_in, keys: [:attribute])` should be `devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:create, keys: [:attribute])`

Comment: If I do that, I get the error: ActionController::UnknownFormat in Users::SessionsController#create, and it points to the create method (the super line) as the issue